# Rails 4 json response only after refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using a `respond_to` block to feed some json into a calendar.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render json: @reservations, root: false}
end
```

The Json is formatted using the `active_model_serializers` gem.

```
class ReservationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

def attributes
  super.merge(start: object.reservation_start, 
                end: object.reservation_end,
                title: object.user.username,
                url: edit_reservation_path(object),
                color: object.transport.color,
                updateUrl: reservation_path(object),
                transport_id: object.transport_id,
                user_id: object.user.id,
               )
  end
end
```

If I go to `localhost:3000` and click the `localhost:3000/reservations`, my calendar is empty, but after I refresh the page the data is there. Also, if I visit `localhost:3000/reservations` directly everything works fine.
At first I was blaming javascript/assets pipeline, so I wrote some `console.log` to debug and the javascript for the calendar was being loaded normaly.

The calendar initializer:

```
$ ->
  $(".calendar").fullCalendar
    lang: 'pt-BR'
    events: gon.path
    timeFormat: "HH:mm"
    displayEventEnd: true
    eventDrop: updateEvent
    eventResize: updateEvent
    console.log("TEST")
```

Comment: Please share the block of code, which you have used to initialize your Calendar!

Comment: I may have found one of the causes. The `gon.path` variable is undefined until the page is refreshed, so it has nothing to do with the json response.